# django-cms: Can't get CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF to work

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I got a placeholder defined as

```
{% placeholder "banner-mobile" %}
```

And in `settings.py` I defined:

```
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'banner-mobile': {
        'plugins': ['PicturePlugin'],
        'name':gettext("Banner"),
    },
}
```

But I can still choose a different plugin...

Using:

```
Django==1.7.7
django-cms==3.0.13
```

Comment: in the template you got `banner-desktop` and in the config `banner-mobile`. Is that just a typo?

Comment: As it stands, you've not specified anything for `banner-desktop` so it should offer you all the plugins which you've got installed.

Comment: @BenjaminWohlwend I fixed the wrong code, copy pasted it wrong.

Comment: Hm. Looks right to me. I use Django 1.8 and django-cms 3.4.2 and it works. Maybe upgrading django-cms?